# zIndex not working in local execution. React Native

Tags: react-native, z-index

A few days ago I was creating an app in react native. And everything was going well until the moment I wanted to use the zIndex prop, and at the moment of wanting to use this prop it didn't work as it should. At first I thought it was a mistake on my part, but I decided to try with Expo.io and experiment with the zIndex to see where I was wrong and the following happened:

Local execution:  [image] [image] [image]

Expo.io exectuion: [image][image]

It's practically the same code, however in the local execution the prop zIndex doesn't work

Does anyone know why that happens?

Comment: Why don't you try putting the zIndex style in the component, like: `{{...styles.container, zIndex: 2}}`

Comment: I'm tryng this right now but it doesn't work. Is it a reactnative bug or something?

Comment: Did you try to close and re-open everything?